# Azure Azcopy for Mac Cannot Upload

Tags: azure, azcopy

I tried to upload a directory with this command on Mac but could not work.

./azcopy copy ‘/folder1’ ‘https://company.blob.core.windows.net/SAStoken’ --recursive

What I get in return is this. What is going on here? Thank you.

```
[11] 36667
[12] 36668
[13] 36669
[14] 36670
[15] 36671
[16] 36672
[17] 36673
-bash: --recursive: command not found
[12]   Done                    ss=bfqt
[13]   Done                    srt=co
[14]   Done                    sp=rwac
[15]   Done                    se=2020-04-02T15:59:59Z
[16]   Done                    st=2020-03-19T17:07:24Z
[17]   Done                    spr=https
```

Comment: Can you try with `--recursive=true`? Something like `./azcopy copy ‘/folder1’ ‘https://company.blob.core.windows.net/SAStoken’ --recursive=true`

Comment: Yes ! i did try that too but does not work as well. My AZCOPY executable is in the same folder as the folder that i want to upload (Folder A > azcopy + Folder B). I want to upload Folder B. do i just put "/FolderB" as filepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what the issue is :). Basically you would need to enclose your parameters in either single quote (`'`) or double quotes (`"`) however you are enclosing them in `‘` and that is causing the azcopy command to fail.

Please try something like the following:

```
./azcopy copy './folder1' 'https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container?sasToken' --recursive
```

This should work.

Comment: i tried double quotes " as well, and i specify the full file path. I tried this ./azcopy copy "/Users/Joe/Documents//folderB" "https://company.blob.core.windows.net/SAStoken" --recursive=true , but then i got this error "wrong number of arguments". Please help!

Comment: Let's say you're running it from inside folderA and you need to copy `folder1` which is inside that. Then the above command should work. Also, I don't see blob container name in your destination URL.

Comment: the SAS URL is:  htt ps://company.blob.core.windows.net/somewords?sv=2019-02-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwac&se=2020-04-02T15:59:59Z&st=2020-03-19T17:07:24Z&spr=https&sig=somestring  (added space bar to https)

Answer (score 1):

The issue as stated above is with the way you have used the quotes.

```
 azcopy copy '/Users/xyx/wwi.bak.txt' 'https://xyz01.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/wwd.bak.txt?<token>'
```

Answer (score 0):

For MAC users please beware of the difference between “ and ". Use the latter!!!

Copy this " for your file path

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have azcopy installed, you have to install it:

brew install azcopy